# How to open a modal in Drupal 8 without using a link?

Tags: ajax, modal-dialog, drupal-8

The modal isn't triggered by a link on the page which the user has clicked. The modal is triggered when the user arrives on the url.

Think of something like a disclaimer that pops up as soon as the user arrives on the url.

Comment: see if this helps http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/how-to-load-modal-form-on-page-load-using-ctools

Comment: That post is about Drupal 7, not 8.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `Drupal.dialog` function for this.

For example:

```
var $myDialog = $('<div>My dialog text</div>').appendTo('body');
Drupal.dialog($myDialog, {
  title: 'A title',
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Close',
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }]
}).showModal();
```

See `node.preview.js` for another example.

**Update**: To use this with an AJAX request/response:

```
Drupal.ajax({
  url: 'some/path',
  success: function(response) {
    var $myDialog = $('<div>' + response.data + '</div>').appendTo('body');
    Drupal.dialog($myDialog, {title: 'Some title'}).showModal();
  }
}).execute();
```